# How to keep selection after changing the page using smart-table?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I am using smart-table (1) to allow the user to choose records from different pages, that are show in a preview div.

The current issue is that when I choose some records from the first page, navigate to the seconds, and navigate back to the first, the selection in the first page does not reflect the previous selection.

The current selection if saved in a map called operatorSelection (2), and my first try was to select the rows again after the onChangedSource event (3), but even after calling multipleSelectRow() the getSelectedRows() does not return the expected rows.

Is there any other way to keep the selection after the page change? or other way to select rows from the code?

Here are the fragments of code:

(1) The compoment html

`<div class="col-lg-6">
         <ng2-smart-table #grid [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)">
    </ng2-smart-table>
</div>`

(2) The component code for row selection

```
onUserRowSelect(event) {
console.log('on UserRowSelect', event, this.operatorSelection);

if (event.isSelected) {
  this.operatorSelection.set(event.data.code, event.data);
} else {
  this.operatorSelection.delete(event.data.code);
}

this.updatePreview();
}
```

(3) what I tried to update the selection after the page changed

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.table.grid.source.onChangedSource.subscribe(() => {
  this.operatorSelection.forEach((row) => {

    this.table.grid.source.data.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.code == row.code) {
        console.log('--- reselect ', row.code );
        this.table.grid.multipleSelectRow(row);
        console.log('*** selected ', this.table.grid.getSelectedRows() );
      }
    });
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses local storage to store data while traversing through components, by what you have mentioned above the datasource is refreshed onInit of the component.

You have to use services to store data that you wish to retain while to traverse and set this data to the datasource by onInit of the component.